# Get the value of Error-Message in failure block of AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, objective-c, afhttprequestoperation

I need to get the value of Error-Message in the failure block of my request.

Here's the error:

> Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011
>   "Request failed: bad request (400)" UserInfo=0x165151b0
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://203.125.112.203:8090/megumi01/api/zipData?lastSynced=1441161682,
>   com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response= { URL:
>   http://203.125.112.203:8090/megumi01/api/zipData?lastSynced=1441161682
>   } { status code: 400, headers {
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "x-requested-with, Authorization, Content-Type, Accept";
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT";
>       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
>       "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 3600;
>       "Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate";
>       Connection = close;
>       "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
>       Date = "Wed, 02 Sep 2015 10:38:57 GMT";
>       "Error-Code" = 0808;
>       "Error-Message" = "No updates available";
>       Expires = 0;
>       Pragma = "no-cache";
>       Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
>       "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
>       "X-Application-Context" = "application:9090";
>       "X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
>       "X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
>       "X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block"; } }, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: bad request (400)}

I have tried putting "error" into NSData so I could convert it to NSDictionary but it becomes nil.

May I know how could I get the value of the custom header "Error-Message"?

TYIA!

Comment: what type of value do you need? int err = 400?

Comment: @Yuri I actually need the value of "Error-Code" and "Error-Message".

Answer (score 0):

below code may help you. try it.

```
NSLog(@"status code  :%ld",(long)[operation.response statusCode]);
NSLog(@"Failure Response %@, %@", error, operation.response.description);
```

Comment: In the latest AFNetworking, the responseObject is nil in failure block. That's why we have decided to add a custom header. But I couldn't get the value of the custom header.

Answer (score 0):

After thinking straightly, I was able to get the proper way to get the custom header in failure block of AFHTTPRequestOperation.

```
NSDictionary *userInfo = [error userInfo];
NSHTTPURLResponse *alamofireResponse = [userInfo objectForKey:@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response"];
NSDictionary *allHeaders = [alamofireResponse allHeaderFields];
NSString *customMessage = [allHeaders objectForKey:@"Error-Message"];
```